# What does "Of" mean in the beginning of "Of mice and men"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The title of one of John Steinbeck's novels:

> Of Mice and Men

In Iran this novel has been translated to Persian word by word without considering the **Of** many years ago. It is just **Mice and Humans** not **Of Mice and Men**.

Is it only the taste of translator or had s/he been right in translating it like this? Does **Of** easily only mean **From** or something else?

I have to add the *men* in the title has been translated to *humans* in Persian. I know *man* or *men* can mean *human* in English but it would be better to be sure about that.

Comment: This is a confusing construction in English, so +1 for the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Of*, in this context, means *regarding*. So a "translated" title might be, "**Regarding** Mice and Men."

Comment: Or, if you wanted to use another preposition, you could use _about_: _About Mice and Men_.

Comment: @J.R.: Fair enough. Either adds clarity to the ambiguous "of."

Comment: It is also, in this context, a reference to another work: Robert Burns' "To a Mouse" i.e. (in English rather than the original Scots) "The best laid schemes of mice and men / Often go awry". That context is important, I think.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is a poetic way of saying "This is a story of mice and men". I think it was fashionable mid 20th century. I've read another book called "Of Whales and Men", written in 1950.

Comment: Even more famous, Darwins's [***On** the Origin of Species*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species). Different preposition, but the same general principle. I'm not sure it's necessarily a "poetic" usage though.

Comment: So it means the translator has not made a radical change in the title.

Comment: @Persian Cat: The title would be problematic in *any* translation, since [it alludes to](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081007175614AAEKGh9) Robert Burns [*The best-laid schemes o' mice an' men
Gang aft agley*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse) (*...often go wrong*, in modern English).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You could probably turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: @snailboat: Perhaps I haven't quite understood the focus of your question. I think Mark's answer here adequately covers the question I *thought* was being asked (what does "of" mean here, and does it therefore need to be translated?). The matter of *why* the book was thus titled seems to me to be a somewhat different question. And quite possibly the matter of ***how** it could be translated into Persian* may actually be unanswerable, since it depends on a cultural reference that's probably not available to the target readership.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, that's a fair point.  I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: @snailboat: I've just noticed Tom Au's suggested "regarding". If the Persian equivalent of a word like that could reasonably be used in such contexts, then go for it. Susan Sontag is a competent writer, and her latest book is called [Regarding the Pain of Others](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Regarding-Pain-Others-Susan-Sontag/dp/0141012374). It's quite a normal usage in such contexts. Or you could replace it with "A tale of", as in Dickens' [A Tale of Two Cities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Cities)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just to be clear, Persian Cat and I are separate people.  I don't know the Persian language and it's not my question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and snailboat thanks for your constructive comments. I got what I was searching for. The translator has done his/her bests to translate it in a neutral form.

Comment: @snailboat: Ooops, sorry about that! I was flicking between this one and the question you [*did* ask on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/662/) (computers and women can multi-task - but not me, obviously! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with snailboat about that different question in the meta however I was one of closevoters and believe that it was the best decision. Under this topic you put good comments. I hope you keep it in the future! :)